# Bootstrap - Alignments are off, not sure how to fix it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm pooped, I can't get elements to line up and I'm drowning in div soup. What am I missing here?

The Date and Time element is misaligned, but I feel that is part of a larger structural problem. Additionally, the final version has the radio buttons aligned along the top of its respective container, I tried using align-self but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Where I am currently:
[image: Where I am]

What the result should be:
[image: Where I need to be]

```
    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 offset-md-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <h3 class="card-header bg-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- Number of Guests -->
              <label for="numberOfGuests" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><strong>Number of Guests</strong></label>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">4</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">5</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">6</label>
              </div>
            <!-- Date and Time -->
              <div class="row">
                <label for="dateAndTime" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><strong>Date and Time</strong></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div class="row row-content align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 offset-md-2 col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header bg-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <!-- Number of Guests -->
          <div class="row">
            <label for="numberOfGuests" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><strong>Number of Guests</strong></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
              </div>
              ...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Date and Time -->
          <div class="row">
            <label for="dateAndTime" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><strong>Date and Time</strong></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]